# Editing input fields in react seeding with default

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal where a user is supposed to edit what he entered in a table. When I set-state using static getDerivedStateFromProps, the user cannot modify the input box, but when I manually initialize the state with some arbitrary data, the user can modify it.  What am I doing wrong?

the component is getting its props from redux.

```
export default class EditItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: ""

    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    let { value, name } = event.target;
    this.setState({
       [name]: value
    })
  }


  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    return {
      name: nextProps.itemDetails.name
    }
  }

  render() {
    let {

    } = this.state;
    let {itemDetails} = this.props
    return (
      <div id="myModal3" className="modal fade">
        <div id={uuidv1()} className="modal-dialog">
          <div id={uuidv1()} className="modal-content">

            <div id={uuidv1()} className="modal-body">
              <form id={uuidv1()} className="form-horizontal form-material">
                {this.props.cat_name}
                <div id={uuidv1()} className="form-group">
                  <label id={uuidv1()} className="col-md-8">
                    Item Name
                  </label>
                  <div id={uuidv1()} className="col-md-8">
                    <input
                      id={uuidv1()}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      value={this.state.name}
                      name="name"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="ex. Burrito"
                      className="form-control form-control-line"
                    />
                  </div>

                </div>



              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code so that it will be easy to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: it says its too big of a component, one sec

Comment: you can use jsfiddle to share the code here

Comment: I just posted it. :)

Comment: you can use componentWillReceiveProps instead of getDerivedStateFromProps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `getDrivesStateToProps` is not a good option like that. You have a prop, why don't you use it directly? You can [look here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) for more explanation.

Set your initial state to your prop:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );

    this.state = {
      name: this.props.itemDetails.name,
    };
  }

  handleChange = ( event ) => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    this.setState( {
      [ name ]: value,
    } );
  };

  render() {
    let { } = this.state;
    const { itemDetails } = this.props;
    console.log( this.state );
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <form>
                {this.props.cat_name}
                <div>
                  <label>Item Name</label>
                  <div>
                    <input
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      value={this.state.name}
                      name="name"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="ex. Burrito"
                      className="form-control form-control-line"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const itemDetails = { name: "foo" };

ReactDOM.render(<App itemDetails={itemDetails}/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If your prop is coming from an async operation, I don't know maybe you can use something like this just to be in the safe side:

```
this.state = {
      name: ( this.props.itemDetails && this.props.itemDetails.name ) || "",
};
```

Maybe there is a better way  ¯(°_o)/¯